# I have this code that works on local host but not on my WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor, onscrollchanged

I have this code that works well on my local host. I tried to put that code on my WordPress to change the logo and hamburger color but it doesn't work. It keeps returning JavaScript errors. Everything else is working properly.

What is wrong with this code and why it doesn't work on my WordPress site?

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var height = $('#scroll-to').offset().top - 70;
  var body = document.body;
    scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= height) body.classList.add('change');
  else body.classList.remove('change');
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand);
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

#menuToggle {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  /* hide this */
  z-index: 2;
  /* and place it over the hamburger */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}


/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */

#menuToggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 1;
  transform-origin: 4px 0px;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0), opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child {
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}


/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}


/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(3) {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}


/** Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~span:nth-last-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}


/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77, 0.2, 0.05, 1.0);
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}


/*
 * And let's slide it in from the left
 */

#menuToggle input:checked~ul {
  transform: none;
}

.change #menuToggle span {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js">
        </script>
      </head>
<body>
<!--    Made by Erik Terwan    -->
<!--   24th of November 2015   -->
<!--        MIT License        -->
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />

    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.
    
    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#">
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>About</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Info</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank">
        <li>Show me more</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="container" #slide-1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1 col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
      <h1>Full Screen Burger Menu</h1>
      <h3>Click the burger.</h3>
      <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet darth lando qui-gonn mara droid jade qui-gonn skywalker wedge lars. Ben antilles chewbacca palpatine mothma fisto binks mara. Wicket greedo c-3p0 han lars mara darth. Darth binks wookiee mara luuke amidala. Lando kessel
        jango wicket. Moff jango dantooine luuke skywalker obi-wan. Darth mandalore binks leia solo moff yoda. Darth c-3p0 maul ben jar lando. Jabba ahsoka grievous mandalorians kenobi wookiee chewbacca. Binks calrissian tatooine baba jango k-3po darth
        calamari yavin.</p>
      <p>
        Wicket sidious organa skywalker mandalore mon qui-gonn fisto. Leia grievous biggs bespin calamari. Alderaan luuke darth hutt. Vader leia boba kashyyyk dagobah jade kashyyyk. Lars amidala gonk lobot organa. Twi'lek darth gamorrean obi-wan boba moff. Yavin
        c-3p0 darth darth luke chewbacca han. Skywalker dooku c-3po owen. Leia jade alderaan jar dooku utapau tusken raider dantooine jawa. Anakin leia kessel jango bespin lando organa tatooine tusken raider. Mara ackbar mara calamari hutt qui-gonn dantooine.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="scroll-to" style="background-color:#000;width:100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-push-1 col-md-8 col-md-push-2">
      <h1>Full Screen Burger Menu</h1>
      <h3>Click the burger.</h3>
      <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet darth lando qui-gonn mara droid jade qui-gonn skywalker wedge lars. Ben antilles chewbacca palpatine mothma fisto binks mara. Wicket greedo c-3p0 han lars mara darth. Darth binks wookiee mara luuke amidala. Lando kessel
        jango wicket. Moff jango dantooine luuke skywalker obi-wan. Darth mandalore binks leia solo moff yoda. Darth c-3p0 maul ben jar lando. Jabba ahsoka grievous mandalorians kenobi wookiee chewbacca. Binks calrissian tatooine baba jango k-3po darth
        calamari yavin.</p>
      <p>
        Wicket sidious organa skywalker mandalore mon qui-gonn fisto. Leia grievous biggs bespin calamari. Alderaan luuke darth hutt. Vader leia boba kashyyyk dagobah jade kashyyyk. Lars amidala gonk lobot organa. Twi'lek darth gamorrean obi-wan boba moff. Yavin
        c-3p0 darth darth luke chewbacca han. Skywalker dooku c-3po owen. Leia jade alderaan jar dooku utapau tusken raider dantooine jawa. Anakin leia kessel jango bespin lando organa tatooine tusken raider. Mara ackbar mara calamari hutt qui-gonn dantooine.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
      <p>
        Yoda sidious lando padmé chewbacca fett. Maul calrissian boba lobot jade darth obi-wan. Wookiee darth ahsoka dagobah darth sidious naboo lars. Dooku skywalker skywalker ben luke windu. Wicket darth coruscant darth coruscant organa palpatine yoda padmé.
        Darth leia organa gonk lando mon mara hutt. Wookiee darth padmé windu hutt. Darth cade maul padmé grievous greedo moff dooku solo. Coruscant twi'lek dooku moff skywalker.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe replace **$** with **jQuery** in your javascript will fixed the error:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   var height = jQuery('#scroll-to').offset().top - 70;
   var body = document.body;
   scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

   if (scroll >= height) body.classList.add('change');
   else body.classList.remove('change');
});
```